# Get rid of Dependancy on App.config in Data Source

Tags: .net, datasource

I made the huge mistake of "trying out" the data sources in VS2008. I had a load of fields on the form I needed to populate and figured in this one case I'd do a data source so that I could drag and drop the columns into the form.

All works ok.. however, I had to fiddle with the Designer of my data source to override the connection string (we use our own encrypted strings)

```
        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
     Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")>  _
    Private Sub InitConnection()
        Me._connection = New Global.System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection()
        ' ** Override default designer settings - get conn string from CORE **
        Me._connection.ConnectionString = Core.DBManager.ConnectionString
    End Sub
```

Again, this works. It's a bit of a pain as I have to override it any time the data source changes.

Now onto the main issue. I want UAC compatibility and the *only* thing preventing this is the connection string setting which the Data Source automatically creates for itself (even though I have over ridden it and am not using it!). App.config tries to create itself in the install dir in program files so the app wont' even launch on a UAC machine. I don't want to look into moving app.config anywhere as that isn't the solution since the config isn't' even needed.

I can't see a way to get rid of this dependency.. I don't even need or want the connection string in my app.settings as I use my own internal one as per above code sample.

[image: Data source connection pointing to (unused!) app.config setting]

[image: The setting I really want rid of]

Deleting the setting messes up the data source at design time - you can no longer edit it until you put the setting back in.

Removing the data source approach and doing it manually as I do everywhere else isn't currently an option due to time constraints.

Comment: Did you sort this Janine?  I've inherited a system with this scenario.